# xml descendants looping issue in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am unable to get values from xml while looping, i want to get values of each and every element inside HostedService. For e.g. service name, Url etc.

Below is my code

```
XDocument doc;
using (Stream input = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\Test.xml"))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(input);

    foreach (var events in doc.Root.Descendants("HostedServices")) // loop through all events
    {

    }
}
```

XML example:

```
<HostedServices     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure"xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                 
<HostedService>
    <Url>https://www.google.com</Url>
    <ServiceName>sharepoint2013vm</ServiceName>
    <HostedServiceProperties>
      <Description i:nil="true" />
      <Location>East Asia</Location>
      <Label>c2hhcmVwb2ludDIwMTN2bQ==</Label>
      <Status>Created</Status>
      <DateCreated>2015-01-13T03:42:21Z</DateCreated>
      <DateLastModified>2015-01-13T03:42:46Z</DateLastModified>
      <ExtendedProperties>
        <ExtendedProperty>
          <Name>ResourceGroup</Name>
          <Value>sharepoint2013vm</Value>
        </ExtendedProperty>
        <ExtendedProperty>
          <Name>ResourceLocation</Name>
          <Value>East Asia</Value>
        </ExtendedProperty>
      </ExtendedProperties>
    </HostedServiceProperties>
  </HostedService>
  <HostedService>

  </HostedService>
</HostedServices>
```

Comment: Your code says `HostedServices`, not `HostedService`.

Comment: yes i tried changing its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
        XDocument doc;

        using (Stream input = System.IO.File.OpenRead("XMLFile1.xml"))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(input);

            XmlNamespaceManager nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            nm.AddNamespace("ns", ns.NamespaceName);

            foreach (var hostedService in doc.Root.XPathSelectElements("ns:HostedService",nm)) // loop through all events
            {
                if (hostedService.XPathSelectElement("ns:ServiceName", nm) != null)
                {
                    var service = hostedService.XPathSelectElement("ns:ServiceName",nm).Value;
                }
                if (hostedService.XPathSelectElement("ns:Url",nm) != null)
                {
                    var url = hostedService.XPathSelectElement("ns:Url",nm).Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Modified to take care of namespaces. This works now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Test.xml");
```

to load the XML file in memory.

You have to use `XNamespace` since your original XML declares one:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure";
```

To loop through all elements of `<HostedService>` use this:

```
foreach (var events in doc.Descendants(ns+"HostedService").Elements()) 
{

}
```

The above `foreach` will give you access to all *child* `Elements()` of `<HostedService>`, i.e.

1. `<Url>`
2. `<ServiceName>` **and**
3. `<HostedServiceProperties>`

If, on the other side, you want to access all elements (including child elements etc.) below `<HostedService>` then use the following ;

```
 foreach (var events in doc.Descendants(ns + "HostedService").DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>())
 {
 }
```

The above gives you access to:

1. `<Url>`
2. `<ServiceName>`
3. `<HostedServiceProperties>`
4. `<Description>`
5. `<Location>`
6. `<Label>`
7. ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `XML` namespace with your element name:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure";
foreach (var events in doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "HostedServices"))
{

}
```

Have a look at [Working with XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I tried the above code by changing the Descendant value to "HostedService". I am getting Main HostedService element.

But if i try this it does not work events.Element("ServiceName").Name